# Delay in simultaneous requests with redux-saga

Tags: react-native, redux, redux-saga

Hello React Native developers. I'm currently dealing with very strange behaviour in my app. I'm using redux and redux-saga for state management and I'm trying to make simultaneous requests using `all` effect. The problem is that every time one of the two requests is two times longer than it should be. The screenshot below describes it perfectly. It has been captured from Chrome's Inspector.

[image]

As you can see requests have started at the same time. Each call should be approximately 2 seconds long, but when run in parallel one of them lasts 4 seconds. And it seems to be random. Sometimes it's the first one, other time it's the second one. Why is it happening? These are the only two requests that are being called by app at the moment, so the maximum parallel connections is not exceeded. Is it react-native issue or maybe redux-saga?

Comment: Hard to answer this without more information, the code from your sagas, etc. Just to rule it out, what endpoint are you making the requests to? If it's a development server is it possible that it can only process one request at a time?

Comment: Yes. It's development server, but we use the same api for our angular web application and it works as expected - no delay in simultanous calls. Furthermore our web app make even more simultanous requests at the same time, than our react-native app.